# How can I introduce labels that show what points represent?

Tags: r, plot

[image]

Hello, in what way can I neatly show what points correspond to which sample of "soy yoghurt", "oat yoghurt" and "activia".

The code I have used to generate the plot is here

```
color_type = rep("white", length(sample_type))
color_type[soy_yoghurt] = "brown"
color_type[oat_yoghurt] = "blue"
color_type[activia] = "gold"



pch_type = rep(NA, length(sample_type))
pch_type[all_yoghurt] = 21 # Circle symbols

# run the mds algorithm
mds = metaMDS(bray_dist)

#plot the results


par(mar=c(5,5,2,2), xpd = TRUE)
plot(main= "Ordination of milk-products",
mds$points[,1], mds$points[,2], cex = 3, pch = pch_type,
col = "black", bg = color_type, xlab = "NMDS1", ylab = "NMDS2"
```

Comment: Look up the text() function. There's a handy guide here: https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

Comment: Thank you @olorcain. I have added this line:
#text(mds$points[,1], mds$points[,2], sample_type, cex=0.6, pos=4, col="black")
but now it adds text to the points that are not even displayed. Do you know how I can add a box in the top corner that just shows what each color-dot corresponds to?

Comment: See the `legend` function. For more info on base graphics see Murrell's book "R Graphics" or some of the free material online (e.g., sections 15 and 25 in my book here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325170649_An_Introduction_to_R_for_Beginners). You might also check out the popular ggplot2 package. The `ggplot` function automatically adds legends, and `geom_text` or `geom_label` can help with the labels. There is a lot of documentation on the package online.